# How do you show request-response semantics in AsyncAPI?

Tags: spring-kafka, asyncapi

I am going through the specifications for Async API, but I can't find anything that would represent a request/response semantic for a channel.  I am thinking from the context of Spring-Kafka with the `@SendTo` annotation that allows a response message to be sent to an arbitrary channel specified by the requester.

Comment: Your question is not clear; we do have an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1189) to allow a `Future<?>` or `Mono<?>` return type to a listener method (like we support with RabbitMQ) but, as you can see in the issue, there will be problems with offset management.

Comment: This is meant more for https://www.asyncapi.com/ but using Spring Kafka's sendto annotation as a context.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to define this kind of custom things for a specific framework is to use a specification extension. E.g.:

```
asyncapi: 2.0.0
...
channels:
  myTopic:
    subscribe:
      x-spring-kafka: # You can probably come up with a better name :)
        sendTo: myOtherTopic
      ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, there's a discussion about request/reply semantics here: https://github.com/asyncapi/asyncapi/issues/94.